# "deployment optimization failed with 1104 " error when deploying wp8 app using deployment tool

Tags: deployment, windows-phone-8

I am stuck in strange situation, I developed windows phone 8 application for my client and fully tested it on my nokia lumia 920(I also checked deployment using deployment tool as well and its working fine) , then I sent .xap file to my client so that he can install this application using deployment tool , to his wp8. But when he installed this app using deployment tool there comes this error:

> deployment optimization failed with 1104

He tried on Nokia 850 and Lumia 920 but same error!  According to him , his device is also developer unlocked.

Can any one tell me why  there is problem in deploying application ?

Answer (score 0):

I asked my client to - REPAIR - his SDK and this solved the problem. Dnt know what he was missing but seems like there were some thing corrupted for windows phone SDK.